# Constructing a Complete Binary Tree of given height from a number of given 2D coordinates

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to write a program that will initially receive the number of nodes to be given in the next lines and the desired height of the complete binary tree to be produced, with the 2D coordinates of those nodes in the following lines.

It will, then, try to construct an acceptable complete binary tree with those 2D coordinates, in which no two edges are allowed to intersect. (Example below).

If such a tree exists, it should return the number of the position of each node in such a tree (with 1 being the root and all others nodes being numbered incrementally from top to bottom and left to right) in the same order that the nodes came in the input, and nodes that aren't used in the tree should be numbered 0. If such a tree doesn't exist at all, it should print: "No complete binary tree here!"

I've tried range trees and k-d trees to no avail, as I'm having difficulty trying to wrap my head around how to check if the tree can be constructed in any angle, e.g. with it going down on the x-axis or y-axis, or any other line for that matter. I'd appreciate any approach you could provide.

Example input:

```
9 2
(100,300)
(200,300)
(500,301)
(200,200)
(300,201)
(400,203)
(500,206)
(300,101)
(402,100)
```

Corresponding output:

```
4, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 6, 5, 7
```

For a visual depiction of what I mean, you can take a look at this image:

[image]

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Comment: As a possible starting point, note that the root of the tree must be an *extremal point* of the set of (used) node coordinates. You can compute the convex hull of the input point set and test each point on the hull as a possible root candidate. Rejection is a little trickier though - excluding certain convex hull points may result in new candidates.

Comment: So your output tells the insertion indices of all the nodes, according to their place in the tree? E.g., the node in index 4 is going to be the root and the node in index 1 is its left child? But what is your comparison function? How is the tree sorted? InOrder?

Comment: @SomethingSomething OP didn't state the need for a binary *search* tree.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog So why are the node indices not as same as their insertion order? Something changed their order according to his output

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Thanks for the much needed edit, I'm a complete tyro here.

Comment: @SomethingSomething hmm OP's visual depiction example wasn't quite what I expected. They need to explain in more detail what they meant by "acceptable" – maybe that the edges cannot intersect? Anyhow the nodes seem to be sorted in order of rotation about their parent nodes.

Comment: @kelalaka Thanks for the heads up. I added a link to a drawing for the example.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Yes, exactly. It's acceptable if it's complete and the edges don't intersect. I forgot to state the latter, I'll edit my question and add that right now.

Comment: @kelalaka I'm assuming you're referring to the coordinates, but I didn't quite get what you're asking. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: I think this is always possible, provided you have at least 2^(n-1)+1 nodes; you can take leaves from the convex hull and build upwards/inwards toward the root, always making sure to take nodes that are on the convex hull of the set of nodes-not-yet-taken. (Easier said than done, of course.)